# C# Char Array - assigning, changing, displaying

Tags: c#, arrays

I am working through Joyce Farrell's Visual C#2012 on my own (this is not a homework assignment).  I have been stuck on this for the past two days, and have yet to find an answer that I understand.  I am looking for a simple program - nothing fancy as I probably haven't read that chapter yet.  :-)  The problem that I am having is when I am trying to show '*' for a non-guessed or incorrectly guessed letter.  If I assign '*' it looks good for the first letter, but when the user enters a second guess, it changes the second guess to a '?'.  Why is that?  Any help would be really appreciated.  Thank you.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] mysteryWordList = { "green", "snowflake", "tree", "joy", "red", "gift", "frozen", "merry" };
        string mysteryWord; // hidden word
        char[] mysteryWordArray;
        char letterGuessed;
        char[] guessWordArray;

        Random ranNumberGenerator = new Random();              // generate a random number, at least 0 but < 8
        int randomNumber = ranNumberGenerator.Next(0, 8);

        mysteryWord = mysteryWordList[randomNumber];  // select a word from list using random number
        Console.WriteLine("The Mystery word is:  " + mysteryWord);  // print word for my validation

        mysteryWordArray = mysteryWord.ToArray();  // put mystery word into array to compare against guessWord array
        Console.Write("MysterywordArray is:  ");
        Console.WriteLine(mysteryWordArray);

        guessWordArray = new char[mysteryWord.Length]; // assign length to user guess array

        // write mystery word in *'s
        for (int x = 0; x < mysteryWord.Length; ++x)
            Console.Write("*");
        //guessWordArray[x] += '%'; adds value and then does not work...
        Console.WriteLine();



        while (guessWordArray != mysteryWordArray)
        {
            Console.Write("\nPlease guess a letter: ");
            letterGuessed = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int x = 0; x < mysteryWord.Length; ++x)// go through each letter in mystery word
            {
                if (letterGuessed == mysteryWordArray[x])  // if match do this
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Yes, the letter {0} is in the mystery word!", letterGuessed);
                    guessWordArray[x] += letterGuessed;
                }
                if (letterGuessed != mysteryWordArray[x] && guessWordArray[x] == default(char))  // if match do this

                        guessWordArray[x] += '*';
                }
                Console.Write("Mystery Word:  ");
                Console.WriteLine(guessWordArray);



        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help, my question has been successfully answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This two lines :

```
guessWordArray[x] += letterGuessed;
....
guessWordArray[x] += '*';
```

should be like this instead :

```
guessWordArray[x] = letterGuessed;
....
guessWordArray[x] = '*';
```

By this `+=` operator, you are appending the char from user input to existing char saved in the array. That will produce special character which which won't be displayed well in console (that's why you saw sort of `?` char). I think you need to just assign the input char and replace existing char by using `=` instead of `+=`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.  Fantastic!  That did the trick!  I should have posted on her a lot sooner.

Comment: by this `+=` operator, you are appending the char from user input to existing char saved in the array. I think you need to just assign the input char and replace existing char by using `=` instead of `+=`

Comment: Oh, that makes sense!!  Thank you for adding the explanation.  So glad I joined!  Until next time...

Answer (score 4):

The command `guessWordArray[x] += letterGuessed;` is wrong. It dosent add the letter to the array it actualy changes the Xth element in the array. For example if guesswordArray contains `{ 'a', 'b', 'c' }`

`guesswordArray[0] += 'a'` translates to `guessWordArray[2] = 'a' + 'a'`. Character addition is done by converting a character to the ascii code then the result is converted to a character. That means `'a'== 97` `'a'+'a' == 194'` Then 194 is converted back to a weird character from the ascii table.

Comment: +1 for explaining why his code is faulty in addition to how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Characters are essentially integers in their most basic form. When you are attempting to add subsequent letters to your array you are using `+=` which is adding characters together. The initial character '*' is ASCII code 42, so what's happening is when you select a new letter ('g' for example in "gift") you are adding 103 to to that 42, and the ASCII character with the value 145 is being stored in the array. That value is unable to be displayed properly by the console. You need to just use the assignment operator since you want to write the new character to the array at the current index.

`guessWordArray[x] = letterGuessed;`

`guessWordArray[x] = '*';`